# How to hide Keyboard which is in another window? Swift

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard, frameworks, uiwindow

I have a framework, which has a new window and and in that window, I have a button. Now I have imported that framework in my Host app, and now I have a floating button. So now when I tap on that button, an alert appears from the bottom. But the problem comes, when the keyboard is open in the host app window and I try to click that button, the alert opens but is hidden behind the keyboard. How do I dismiss that keyboard as soon as button is clicked? How can I dismiss keyboard of a window from anther window? Or this will also work for me if I can set my framework window level higher than the keyboard window level. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Type `view.endEditing(true)` just before the method that opens the alert.

Comment: I am in another window, it will only end editing for the current window. I want to end editing for another window

Comment: Use protocol and delegate or NSNotificationCenter using that close the keyboard..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, get a reference to host app keyWindow

```
  func getHostKeyWindow() -> UIWindow? {
    if #available(iOS 13, *) {
        return windows.first { $0.isKeyWindow }
    } else {
        return keyWindow
    }
}
```

And then simply make `endEditing` as `true`

```
UIApplication.shared.getHostKeyWindow()?.endEditing(true)
```

It should close the keyboard in the window for which you have the reference!